# Why is this MYSQL SELECT QUERY returning a match on a wrong condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

My database structure is:

```
    CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` char(20) NOT NULL,
  `pass` char(60) NOT NULL,
  `email` char(100) NOT NULL,
  `mobile_no` char(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   ....
```

I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid='1zasdasd' LIMIT 1
```

and this returns the record matching uid='1'

How's that happening? When "=" requires an exact match.

Comment: You're comparing a number with a string. It converts the string to a number. So it's equivalent to `WHERE uid = 1`

Comment: so "1zasdasd" converted to a number is "1"? strange

Comment: Yes. Try `SELECT CAST('1zaddasd' AS DECIMAL)`